# Hover effect is working in chrome but not working in Firefox

Tags: css

```
.thumbnail{
position: relative;
z-index: -99;
height:125px;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color: transparent;
z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #512C1D;
    padding: 10px 0px 0 10px;
    border: 0px solid gray;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow:none;
    height:210px;
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border: 1px solid #512C1D;
padding: 0px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
visibility: visible;
top: -20%;
left: -35%; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
transition-delay: 1s;
-webkit-transition-delay: 1s; 

}
```

I was trying to add hover effect for thumbnail class and I added, but hover is only working in Chrome Browser, in Firefox it is not working and i could not figure out what is wrong here

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, use:

```
-moz-transition-delay: 1s;
```

There are a few different CSS vendor prefixes available for the popular browsers, you can read about them here:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with your negative z-index.

A negative z-index will prevent your `.thumbnail` from getting the hover state because it is stacked beneath other elements on your page. It may still be visible, but it is not accessible to mouse events. I've created a simplified fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/t3vg2/ (Note the second thumbnail has an auto z-index.)

To fix this you should reconsider your reasoning for setting a negative z-index. Try using the hover state on a parent element that will always be available. For example, if your `.thumbnail` is inside a div, style based on the :hover state of the div rather than the thumbnail. Alternatively, use `opacity` rather than z-index if you just want to hide/show the thumbnail.

I have seen differences in the way Chrome and Firefox handle z-indexes, so this may explain why it works in Chrome and not Firefox.